# metamask transaction successful but shows an unchanged state

Tags: metamask, anvil

I'm running a local anvil network.
This is how I added the network on metamask:

[image: anvil network metamask]

When I run a transaction like transferring ETH from Account 1 to Account 2, the transaction is successful (and on my anvil node the rpc requests appear) **but the balance remains unchanged on both accounts**.

Here is an example (starting balance was 10000):
[image: transaction]

I have tried in 2 different browsers: Google and Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

The problem went away without me doing anything, however I did notice that before the eth_feeHistory method on anvil was not being called.